# Java Client Server

Tags: java, sockets, io, client-server

I am trying to pass message from server to client in terminal. What I would like the program to do is, in the client, it should be able to enter a command, get response from server, and be able to enter another command without restarting Client (by java Client).

*Client.java*

```
Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String response = "";

boolean continuation = true;
while(continuation) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command = (input.nextLine()).toString();
    bw.write(command+"\r\n");
    bw.flush();

    if(command.equals("cmd1") {
        while ((response = br.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(response);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("This line will not execute as well.");
}
```

*Server.java*

```
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

String[] in = br.readLine().split("\\s+");
String command = in[0];

if(command.equals("cmd1")) {
    String response = "";
    response = response + "RESPONSE:\r\n";
    response = response + "This is a response.\r\n";
    bw.write(response);

    bw.flush();
}
```

If I don't put while((response = br.readLine()!= null) { ... } in Client.java, it is possible to enter multiple inputs in the terminal, but if I put it, it prints the response from the server and another input cannot be done without restarting Client.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what do mean of restarting client? You mean to say when response is null the Client.java is getting terminated?

Comment: when I type in some command in terminal and hit enter, a response should be sent by the server which gets printed in the client terminal. however, after that, it is not possible to type in another command and hit enter and receive response from server. I'd have to terminate client and restart it again.

Comment: I'd like it to be able to input command and get response continuously without having to restart Client by java Client

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

server:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

boolean continuation = true;
while (continuation) {
    String command = dis.readUTF();
    //proceeed command
    dos.writeUTF("response");
    dos.flush();
}
```

Client:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeUTF("your command");
    while (dis.available() == 0) {
        try {
            //wait for response
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RandomTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    String response = dis.readUTF();
    //and so on
```

Comment: I'd need to pass string with line break and carriage return. Is that possible through writeUTF? Also, I need to have continuous input from Client. For instance.

cmd1
response from client
(without terminating here)
cmd2
second response from client

Comment: Yes a line break is also possible with writeUTF! If you want to have continuous input from Client you should setup a new Connection over different port or you are waiting all the time for a response and divide response in two types: 1. In the response of command and 2. as general Listener for some other commands..

Comment: how to just loop in client until user enters 'exit'? at the moment, what is happening is server sends a response, the client prints it, and then neither it is going up to the loop to another 'input', nor it is terminating the client. It is just showing the terminal's blinking cursor

Comment: for instance, if I write something outside of if (command.equals...) but inside while(continuation), after getting readLine(), that line of code doesn't even execute

Comment: But you get receive the line?

Comment: I get one response from the server and then I'd have to Ctrl+Z the client and restart client and then type in another command. What I'd like it to have is, without Ctrl+Z ing the terminal, be able to type in another command, and get response

Comment: once response is received in the client, no other lines below while.. readLine() are executed.

Comment: readLine() and readUTF isn't waiting for a response if there is nothing it will be null or just empty! You need to wait for a response like I did in my example! And you need to make sure the connection is still established on client and server side!

Comment: maybe this repository on github helps you to understand how networking works: https://github.com/mmshress/JavaFX-Chat its quite simple!

Comment: why isn't the System.out.println("This line will not execute as well."); line being executed?

Comment: Because your program is stuck in the while loop... try using my example and wait until the input stream contains anything. You can also do dis.readFully(byte[]) but it would be easier to wait like I did!